# Is it okay for wires at the C terminal to touch?

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I just purchased the Honeywell wifi thermostat but my existing thermostat does not have a C wire.  So the instructions given suggest using the G wire as the C wire and at the furnace to move the G wire to the C terminal.  The problem is that my C terminal already has 2 other wires there, is it okay to add another?  Is it okay for those wires to touch?  They also suggested to build a jumper using 18 gauge copper wire from the Y terminal to the G terminal.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with those wires touching. However, screw terminals are commonly only rated for one or two wires to terminate at them. If you're adding a third, it might be time to use a "pigtail".

## Creating a pigtail

- Remove the wires from the screw terminal.
- Combine the two wires that previously were under the screw terminal, with the wire you're adding, and a short bit of scrap wire of the same or larger (smaller gauge) size using a twist-on wire connector (or other approved means).
- Attach the short bit of wire (pigtail) to the screw terminal.